# Free-form queries to the database over HTTP

Tags: database, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am working on providing a REST interface to some database tables.
I want to provide the client a way to fetch data in a dynamic fashion.
e.g.

/customer/1234?active=true&gender=M&wealth>100000&...

So the idea is to have the query string as free form as possible. 
For database access, I'd gather all the query parameters and append them to a SQL where clause and return the response.

I am not sure if there's a key issue here that I might be missing possibly with regards to security.

Is this a good idea? If yes, do you know of such an implementation, can you point me to it?

Comment: Sounds like a security breach for sure - pretty much means a user could tamper with the url to change SQL? Surely a single html form with these params being submitted to a controller should suffice.

Comment: Whats the relevance of JPA here ? since you have it tagged as that. DataNucleus provides a REST interface that connects to a DB behind the scenes, and allows some querying http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/rest/api.html

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if there's a key issue here that I might be missing
>   possibly with regards to security.

One key issue is to prevent ffrom SQL injection. Short reading [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java).

Answer (score 0):

Good idea or not depends entirely on what kind of information the database holds. User accounts : no / Pizza parlors : yes.

You can do it in php as follows:

```
Foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
$clauses[] = $key.' = "'.$value.'"';
}

$query = mysql_query('select * from pizza_parlors where '.explode(' and ',$clauses);
```

But I would make an array with approved search parameters, to restrict any injection methods.